# Add id dynamically to each table cells

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html-table

I am trying to create a dynamic js table and I want to give id to each cell dynamically. I want to use those ids to use in different js event handlers. How it can be done? I have tried in different ways but none of them works!

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #colors {
            float: right;
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var d;
        var k = 0;
        function makeit() {
            var tbl = document.createElement("table");
            var atts = document.createAttribute("style");
            atts.value = "border:1px solid black;text-align:center;padding:2px;margin:3px 3px 3px 3px;";
            tbl.setAttributeNode(atts);
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                var rows = tbl.insertRow(i);

                for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                    d = rows.insertCell(j);
                    d.height = "50px";
                    d.width = "50px";
                    d.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                    d.addEventListener("click", function myfunc() { d.style.backgroundColor = "red"; });


                }
            }


            document.body.appendChild(tbl);
        }

        window.onload = makeit;
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add

```
d.id = "r" + i + "c" + j;
```

under

```
d=rows.insertCell(j);
```

to set unique ids on each `td`.
Obviously, you can change the syntax `r2c4` (which would be 3. row and the 5. cell) to your own liking.

If you want to call a function when clicking on a specific `td` you could even pass the row index (`i`) and column index (`j`) to that function.

**Side note**
You should consider using a JavaScript library or framework like [jQuery](https://jquery.org/) for manipulations like this. It would facilitate your work a lot in the long term.

Comment: as i and j are local variables,how i can use this id outside makeit() function?

Comment: There are a couple of ways: 1. pass it in the function `makeit(i,j)`, 2. parse the id, 3. attach `data` attributes to your `td`, e.g. `d.setAttribute('data-row', i)` and `d.setAttribute('data-column', j)` then you can access the row and column easily by querying those data attributes

Comment: i add an addEventListener lyk this  d.addEventListener("click",myfunc(i,j),false);and then add the function function myfunc(a,b) {
var m=document.getElementById("r" + a + "c" + b);
m.style.backgroundColor="red";
} it is not working :{

Comment: Looks fine to me at first sight. Maybe you can debug by outputting `console.log(m)` after the `getElementById`. If that doesn't help, maybe post a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a scope issue. When adding the event listener, `d`'s reference gets updated to be the last table cell you have created.

You can simply change the event listener's function to:

```
function myfunc() {
     this.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

So that `this` references the object it is attached to. Depending on your intention, you may not need unique ids if you have access to the cell itself.

Comment: thanks!it works but i need to set an id for each cell as i am intend to use this table in different purpose.and i need to use those id outside the makeit() function too .

Answer (score 1):

Using an approach that includes wongcode's solution, you may wish to consider the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myTbl{ border:1px solid black;text-align:center;padding:2px;margin:3px 3px 3px 3px; }
#myTbl td{ width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: yellow;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>

function onCellClicked(e)
{
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}

function makeit()
{
    var tbl=document.createElement("table");
    tbl.id = 'myTbl';
    var curCellIndex = 0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        var rows=tbl.insertRow(i);
        for(j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            d=rows.insertCell(j);
            d.id = 'cell_' + curCellIndex;
            curCellIndex++;
            d.addEventListener("click",onCellClicked, false);
        }
     }
    document.body.appendChild(tbl);
}

window.onload=makeit;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Some of the advantages include:

- Smaller html file created in your editor
- Smaller html code created in the browser
- Use of context and the this keyword
- Smaller memory consumption, since each TD doesn't contain the full
  body of the event handler (it only include a 'pointer' to the
  function to be executed)

**EDIT**: forgot to add code to give the cells an id. Now fixed.