# How with javascript search in <td> for string and then add to that id?

Tags: javascript, string, search, addition

I need find string in table, but the contents of the table is generated using a foreach hasn't assigned id. I want find `<td>` containing text and then I need add to that `<td>` id and then work with it. Is it somehow possible?

--- edit after few hours --
It is much more difficult. I have thead and seeking in it !!SEARCH THIS   .
I just need to find out its position in thead (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc.), so I could continue to work with the entire column.

example code with !!SEARCH THIS  :
`

```
<thead>
  <tr class="listViewHeaders">
   <th width="5%">
    <input type="checkbox" id="listViewEntriesMainCheckBox">
   </th>
   <th nowrap="">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="listViewHeaderValues" data-nextsortorderval="ASC" data-columnname="cf_835">!!SEARCH THIS&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
   </th>
   <th nowrap="">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="listViewHeaderValues" data-nextsortorderval="ASC" data-columnname="createdtime">Created Time&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
   </th>
   <th nowrap="" colspan="2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="listViewHeaderValues" data-nextsortorderval="ASC" data-columnname="smownerid">Assigned To&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
   </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

`

Comment: This post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003341/add-id-dynamically-to-each-table-cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
          var orderColumns = $('a').filter(':contains(SEARCHED STRING)').parent().index();
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

count the number of `td` elements by `document.querySelectorAll('td').length;` then loop and search inside each `td` if `td` equal your `string` set the attribute id to this td element

example :

```js
var len = document.querySelectorAll('td').length;

for (var i=0; i < len; i++){
  if ( document.querySelectorAll('td')[i].innerHTML == "Eve"){
    document.querySelectorAll('td')[i].setAttribute('id', 'yourID')
  }
}
```

```css
#yourID{
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that your content hasn't any id but then you say that you have to add the string to an id.

Wich id are you talking about?

And for information, even in a foreach you can assign an id to your content with a simple counter:

```
int i = 0;
foreach(foo in bar)
{
    <td id=i>some content</td>
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much more difficult. I have thead and seeking in it !!SEARCH THIS   .
I just need to find out its position in thead (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc.), so I could continue to work with the entire column.

example code with !!SEARCH THIS  :
`

```
<thead>
  <tr class="listViewHeaders">
   <th width="5%">
    <input type="checkbox" id="listViewEntriesMainCheckBox">
   </th>
   <th nowrap="">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="listViewHeaderValues" data-nextsortorderval="ASC" data-columnname="cf_835">!!SEARCH THIS&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
   </th>
   <th nowrap="">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="listViewHeaderValues" data-nextsortorderval="ASC" data-columnname="createdtime">Created Time&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
   </th>
   <th nowrap="" colspan="2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="listViewHeaderValues" data-nextsortorderval="ASC" data-columnname="smownerid">Assigned To&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
   </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

`

Answer (score -1):

You could evaluate your `document` with *XPATH* and handle the element afterwards.

```js
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

var element = getElementByXpath("//td[contains(text(),'Eve')]");
element.setAttribute('id', 'someId-' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1))

console.log(element);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I write javascript to .tpl file... I do not know if it would be possible.